# Вебсервер и файлы на разных компьютерах

Tags: веб-сервер, lan

Нужно на одном компе запустить вебсервер, файлы хом-директории которого должны лежать на другом. Есть ли вообще в природе такие вебсервера, которые будут способны взять файлы по сети?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким сервером является, например, любой веб-сервер, поднятый на Linux. Для решения поставленной задачи достаточно смонтировать каталог удалённого сервера в нужный каталог локальной файловой системы (в случае apache это обычно `/var/www`). В этом случае обращения к данному каталогу будут прозрачно перенаправлены операционной системой на сетевой ресурс. То же самое поведение можно реализовать и на Windows, используя монтирование сетевого ресурса на букву диска или каталог NTFS-раздела.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что для начала можно попробовать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OwnCloud

ownCloud — это Свободное и открытое веб-приложение для синхронизации данных, расшаривания файлов и удалённого хранения документов в «облаке».
ownCloud написан на языках программирования PHP и JavaScript. OwnCloud предназначен для работы с несколькими системами управления базами данных, такими как: SQLite, MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle Database, и PostgreSQL.

Один из разработчиков KDE, Франк Карличек, начал разработку ownCloud в январе 2010 г., как бесплатную альтернативу коммерческим сервисам по хранению данных. В отличие от коммерческих файлообменных сервисов, ownCloud можно установить на собственный сервер без дополнительных затрат.

Доступны десктопные клиенты для прямой синхронизации данных с ПК, работающих под управлением Windows, Mac OS или Linux, а также мобильных устройств на iOS и Android. Что еще более важно, сохраненные данные доступны с помощью веб-интерфейса OwnCloud в любом веб-браузере.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.